# Using Mermaid in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, mermaid

I have already tried using both `gatsby-remark-mermaid` and `gatsby-remark-draw` but I kept on getting errors on those plugins. So, I wanted to try the API instead, but it doesn't work as well and I'm not quite sure how to properly use it. Here's what I have so far:

```js
//gatsby-ssr.js

const React = require('react')

export const onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.14.0/mermaid.min.js"/>,
    <script>mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad:true });</script>
  ]);
};
```

Comment: What's the issue with the `setPostBodyComponents`? What do you mean with "doesn't work as well"? Are the scripts loaded?

Comment: I get a red underline on this part `<script>mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad:true });</script>`. What I meant is that, it doesn't produced the desired diagrams and they are only shown as code blocks instead. I'm not sure if the scripts are loaded though.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the scripts like this in the `gatsby-browser.js`:

### Alternative 1

```
export const onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
  setPostBodyComponents([
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.14.0/mermaid.min.js"/>,
  ]);
};


export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
  window.onload = () => {
   mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad:true })
  } 
}
```

More details about `onInitialClientRender`: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#onInitialClientRender

### Alternative 2

```
const addScript = async (url) => {
  const script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = url
  script.async = true
  document.body.appendChild(script)
}

export const onInitialClientRender = () => {
  window.onload = async () => {
    await addScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/8.14.0/mermaid.min.js");
    mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad:true });
  }
}
```

In this case, `script` exposes an `onload` event which may be useful for initializing Mermaid as a callback.

Both ideas rely on the fact that the Mermaid script needs to be loaded before initializing it, that's why the callbacks (`onload`, `async`/`await`, etc). Use the Inspector Tools in the Network tab to check how and when the scripts are loaded and fired.